# Where is Displacement and Bump?

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor

I am revisiting an old tutorial up to 8.24 min, where it´s about displacement and bump under material properties. I am using blender 3.1. This is how it looks then, with the option to use **Displacement and Bumb**...[image: displacement and bump] And here at my screen[image: troll]
It seems like I have to decide between displacement *or* bump in the settings, doesn´t it? Here´s my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1lpazz3scrrlrt/troll_wooly.blend?dl=0
Is that old setup completely gone now? This is Cycles by the way.

Comment: Hi :) You need to be in Cycles for the setting to appear. Because displacement only works in Cycles.

Comment: Ah, it´s right there at Surface.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it´s right there under *Surface*. Somehow I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Searched Surface, searched Displacement ...

Finally found it, it's under :
**Settings** > Surface > Displacement